# ReactJS component redirect stop current component

Tags: reactjs

So on loading of a component, I want to check for a variable, if that variable exists, I want to stop loading that component and redirect them back to the home page. I have this code below that works, but I am getting a stack trace error as the component that redirected the user is still trying to load

```
class Repo extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      repo: {}
    };

  }

  componentWillMount() {
    if (localStorage.getItem('login'))
      this.props.history.push('/');
  }
}
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You could just render the [React Router `<Redirect>`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Redirect) component if that variable exists. Something along these lines.

```
render() {
  if (localStorage.getItem('login')) {
    return (
      <Redirect to={{
        pathname: '/',
        state: { from: routeProps.location }
      }}/>
    );
  } else {
    // Normal rendering here.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work if you move the logic to `componentDidMount`.

Comment: Nope, still getting Warning: Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState, replaceState, or forceUpdate on an unmounted component. This is a no-op.